# Android Checking if a file size has exceeded a certain value

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to set a listener on a created file and alert when the file size has reached a certain value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.
There is a class called `FileObserver` which allows you to listen to certain events, for example when the file is opened, closes or modified. There is no specific listener for the file size, but either the `MODIFY` or the `CLOSE_WRITE`-event is suitable.

Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Short example:

```
observer = new FileObserver(pathToFile,MODIFY + CLOSE_WRITE)
     @Override
     public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
         Log.d(TAG, "File changed[" + pathToWatch + file + "]");
         //TODO: check file size...
     }
 };
 observer.startWatching();
```

Comment: I added a small example

Answer (score 0):

You can check file size changes as follows.

1. Save current file size in preferences or some other storage place
2. create a listener to the file
3. whenever it triggers,compare size of file with the pre-stored size

---

```
curFileSize = fileObject.length();  //size should be stored


  // creating listener
fileObserver = new FileObserver(pathToFile,MODIFY + CLOSE_WRITE)
  @Override
 public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
      //checking size
      if(curFileSize != fileObject.length())
        {
          //there is some change
        }
 }
};
observer.startWatching();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
      double bytes = fileobj.length();
      double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
      double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);

// you can find File size like above....
//if you are Writing a file via output writer you can also check in between file writing Process....that file writer reached at certain Size !!!
```

Comment: i know how to find the file size.... im asking if i can set a listener that checks if the file has reached a certain length